# How do I ping thousands of hosts and show the status as quick as possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concurrency

I need to implement a task in rails which ping huge number of hosts and check if its reachable or not. The result has to be displayed as fast as possible and number of hosts can scale up to some 10k or may be even more.

So far, I have tried to do using thread pool and its taking way long time.

```
      work_q = Queue.new
      @hosts.each{|x| work_q.push x }
      workers = (0...200).map do
           Thread.new do
                begin
                     while host = work_q.pop(true)
                          ping_count = 1
                          server = host.address
                          result = `ping -q -c #{ping_count} #{server}`
                          if ($?.exitstatus == 0) 
                               @res[host.hostname] =  "up"
                          else
                               @res[host.hostname] = "down"
                          end
                     end
                rescue ThreadError
                end
           end
      end;
```

I also tried to use sidekiq to implement it as async task. Here is the way I thought of implementing it.
1. Pass the host ip to the job queue in sidekiq and find the last job id/worker id 
2. Check the status of the last worker id and persist in some way.(not sure how to persist the worker id in better way)
3. Schedule a task to check the completion status of the last worker. Once the last worker is completed restart the sidekiq and ping the hosts all over again.
4. In this way you have the latest status of all hosts (up or down) based on ping result in min interval of time.
5. Whenever user clicks to check the status of hosts, show them the result and it will be latest one.

Can anybody help with any other idea, they can think of to do it in better way. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think the problem might be that you're executing a new process for each ping, so the OS spends quite a bit of the time on the allocation of the process. Have you tried using a library such as [net-ping](https://rubygems.org/gems/net-ping)? This approach should reduce the time considerably. Also, since the work is I/O bound, you can increase the number of threads to maybe something like 2k (depending on the ruby implementation), as most of those threads will be sleeping most of the time.

Comment: @Augusto, Thanks. It's woking as you suggested.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!! I just posted my comment as an answer, feel free to upvote/mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the comment as an answer

I think the problem might be that you're executing a new process for each ping, so the OS spends quite a bit of the time on the allocation of the process. Have you tried using a library such as net-ping? This approach should reduce the time considerably. Also, since the work is I/O bound, you can increase the number of threads to maybe something like 2k (depending on the ruby implementation), as most of those threads will be sleeping most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but a bit of searching just turned up a library called [PacketFu](https://github.com/packetfu/packetfu) which allows you to send ICMP packets from Ruby (it relies on libpcap). It also allows you to sniff packets from Ruby.

So, here's an idea:

Rather than creating a new `ping` process for each and every host you want to ping, use PacketFu to send ICMP echo requests to each host directly from the main Ruby process. At the same time, in a different thread, sniff packets using PacketFu's `Capture` class and match up the source IPs with the addresses you are trying to ping.

You will have to make sure all program state is accessed in a thread-safe manner or things will go BOOM! If you also have a web server or something running in-process for the user-facing interface, it also has to play nice and safe and not stick its little hands in the program state without locking!

Make sure the amount of memory you use is bounded, too! Don't try to keep a record of each and every ICMP echo reply which comes back, or you will have a memory-eating monster! It would be better to just record the last time when a reply came back from each host.

Just one more piece of advice before I send you on your way. Many hosts have firewall rules which limit how many pings they will accept per second. Even if they don't, I assume you are a nice person and don't want to DOS anyone. So don't get out of control and start machine-gunning those pings out at poor innocent people.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have used net-ping as Augusto suggested and its working as expected. Again thanks for the help.